# HTTP request to sharepoint site

Tags: excel, vba, http, sharepoint

I'm trying to see if a file exists on sharepoint. For this is use below code. If I use **"MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0"** then I get an access denied error.

[image: Picture of error]

With **"MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0"** the **oHttpRequest.Status** returns always **200** even if the file is not there. The URL gets passsed with **URLStr** and looks something like this:

```
"https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/abc/def/xyz.xlsx"
```

If I open the file with other VBA code the first example runs fine (maybe because authentication was done somehow?). Online many posts said to add "s" to "http" -> "https", but it changed nothing.

The idea is that the workbook checks online if it is the latest version and if not informs the user. Maybe there is a better way to do this?

```
Public Function checkversionmethod2(URLStr As String) As Boolean

Dim oHttpRequest As Object

'Set oHttpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0") 'authentication issue
Set oHttpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") 'always return 200
   
With oHttpRequest
    .Open "HEAD", URLStr, False ', [UserName], [Password]
    .setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
    .setRequestHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
    .send
End With

If oHttpRequest.Status = 200 Then
    fileexists = 1
Else
    fileexists = 3
End If
    
Set oHttpRequest = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: If I try your posted code from Excel before having opened any file from SharePoint I get the same "access denied": after having opened a file it runs with no problem and produces the expected 404 response if I try to access a non-existent file.  I don't know how to trigger that switch other than opening a "known good" file, so maybe do that in the background (should only be required once per session) before running your version check?

Comment: FYI note your Function code as-posted doesn't return any value - I fixed for testing...

Comment: Thank you for trying out. Opening a good file and reading the version was my inital way for the version check. But some users got access errors trying to open the file eventhough they could do it manually. With the posted code i tried to implement a better way. If i have to open a file for it to work i dont gain anything unfortunately. So maybe i need to get back to my inital way and look why the error occurs.